# DOM Parser Example for Objects within Objects

Tags: java, android

So say I have an XML file that looks like this:

```
<Object1s>
<Object1>
    <Field1></Field1>
    <Object2s>
        <Object2>
            <Field1a></Field1a>
            <Field1b></Field1b>
        </Object2>
        <Object2>
            <Field1a></Field1a>
            <Field1b></Field1b>
        </Object2>
    </Object2s>
</Object1>
<Object1>
    <Field1></Field1>
    <Object2s>
        <Object2>
            <Field1a></Field1a>
            <Field1b></Field1b>
        </Object2>
    </Object2s>
</Object1>
</Object1s>
```

The DOM tutorials I've found have not worked when I try and do the same sort of thing. For instance, I want to be able to separate the Object2s by the Object1 that they are in. When following the example given by DOM tutorials where this type of thing doesn't exist in their XML files, I get all the Object2s that are in any Object1 when I try to find them.

Can someone show me an example that handles something like this?

Comment: How come there's no closing tag for `<Object1s>`? Or is this only part of the file?

Comment: My mistake. I forgot to add 4 spaces there.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, figured it out. What I do is use the element I declare for each element, and within that call .getElementsBytagName() to get the elements within that element.